# Extract Information from Response Body Postman

Tags: javascript, postman

I'm trying to acquire two fields of information of a response body from a VTEX API.

In tests, I currently have:
`` tests[` ${responseBody}`] = true; ``

In return I receive:

[{"categoryId":"default","categoryName":"null","categoryFullPath":null,"productCommissionPercentage":12.00,"freightCommissionPercentage":12.00}]

I'm looking to extract *productCommissionPercentage* and *freightCommissionPercentage* numbers from a list of sellers that I upload via postman runner.

The uploaded CSV looks like this:

```
sellerId

xxxx

yyyy

zzzz
```

I'm looking to have in return something like this, the intent is to easily keep track of seller commisions

```
sellerId productCommissionPercentage freightCommissionPercentage 
    
xxxx     10                          12
    
yyyy     12                          8
    
zzzz     11                          10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the response json in your tests via `pm.response.json()` if that's all you're looking for.

If you want to display the results as a table, add the following to your request's Tests section:

```js
var template = `
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <th>sellerId</th>
        <th>productCommissionPercentage</th>
        <th>freightCommissionPercentage</th>
    </tr>
    
    {{#each response}}
        <tr>
            <td>{{sellerId}}</td>
            <td>{{productCommissionPercentage}}</td>
            <td>{{freightCommissionPercentage}}</td>
        </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
`;

// Set visualizer
pm.visualizer.set(template, {
    // Pass the response body parsed as JSON as `response`
    response: pm.response.json()
});
```

This assumes the response contains the sellerId as a field as well. If it doesn't, you'll need to match it with the ids from your request body, assuming they're in the same order.